# Java change main boolean from Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, boolean

how can I change a boolean which I defined in the Main class from inside a Thread? It doesn't seem to work using `booleanName = true;`.
Is there a way to change the variable's value?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: `thread = new Thread() {public void run() {}}; thread.start();` I want to change the value of a boolean which is defined in the main class from inside this thread

Comment: Please post all of your code, including your Main class.

Comment: All the code is pretty long, but isn't there a way to just change the value of a variable from inside a thread?

Comment: Mark your variable as `volatile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value works just like that. `booleanName = false` if `booleanName` is reachable from your thread code, or something like `Main.setBooleanName(false)` if it is not.

If you want to read that boolean from another thread, you also have to make sure that the new value is visible to your other thread. This can be done by making `booleanName` `volatile`, using a thread-safe boolean type like `AtomicBoolean` or entering/leaving a `synchronized` method or block before reading from `booleanName`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you should post your sample code. If you are asking if you can change the state of a variable from inside the run() method of a thread, yes, of course it's possible.

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private boolean b = true;

    public void run() {
        b = false;
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public boolean getBoolean() {
        return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyThread());
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this code right here: http://pastebin.com/GMf55yNd I want to set a boolean inside the try block to true when the connection was successful or set it to false inside the catch block if it was unsuccessful. How should I do that in this case? The boolean is defined in the main Class, which contains this thread inside a void.

Comment: Still, the problem you are facing isn't not clear from your sample code. Please expand it. "new ChatClient("localhost", 8000).run();" : What are you trying to do hear? Starting another thread?

Comment: I am trying to start a new Netty Client inside this thead and I want to set a boolean to true if the connection was successful or to false when it failed